# Why is QFile::size() not approximately equal to QImage::sizeInBytes()?

Tags: c++, qt

I have an image file, which is labeled by windows as 40KB big in size. I want to convert this image into PDF, but after using QPdfWriter and QPainter I ended up with a 600KB PDF file. I checked some information about the image:

`File size (QFile::size()): 40528` 
`Img size (QImage::size()): QSize(2479, 3508)`
`Img size in bytes (QImage::sizeInBytes()): 1094496`
`Image format (QImage::format()): QImage::Format_Mono`
`Image depth (QImage::depth()): 1`

Why the file size is so much different than image size? Shouldn't the output PDF file take around as much space as the source image? Can I make the image smaller using Compression or different format? It looks like there is something going on during loading the image file into a QImage object. How can I prevent that? I tried saving the file as png using QImage::save() and it successfully saved it as a 35KB file. That means the problem is with writing the image to PDF.

```
void Project::convertImgToPdf()
{
    unsigned int i;
    QString path = projectPath + "/" + projectName + "/output/";
    QDir dir(path + "/img");
    const QString fileName(path + "out.pdf");
    const QPoint imageCoordinates(0,0);
    QPdfWriter pdfWriter(fileName);
    pdfWriter.setResolution(300);
    pdfWriter.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize::A4));
    QPainter painter(&pdfWriter);

    for(i=0;i<dir.count()-2;i++) {
        QImage image(path + "img/img" + QString::number(i));
        if(i>0) {
            pdfWriter.newPage();
        }
        painter.drawImage(imageCoordinates, image);
    }
}
```

Comment: The image size is just uncompressed pixel data. If we round 2479 up to the nearest multiple of 32 (2496), we get `(2496 x 3508) / 8 = 1094496`.

Comment: @JarMan sounds like an answer!

Comment: According to [this](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/4722-Is-possible-to-change-the-compression-level-of-the-images-in-a-PDF-doc), Qt doesn't support PDF compression. But you can ask a followup there.

Answer (score 4):

The image size is just uncompressed pixel data. If we round 2479 up to the nearest multiple of 32 (2496), we get `(2496 x 3508) / 8 = 1094496`.

Note, we divide by 8 because the image is monochrome, so each pixel is a single bit. And of course there are 8 bits per byte.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I have to apply some kind of compression to the image before painting it to the pdf? Or compress the output pdf file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about how Qt writes images to pdfs, or what compression methods they support. If you're already getting a 600KB pdf size, then it must already be compressing it some. Otherwise, the size would be over 1MB.